# Why are there two for-loops in this method for sorting cards in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop

Write a Cards class and a sortCards method such that it sorts a cards array argument such that cards are
ordered in groups of Clubs < Diamonds < Hearts < Spades, and then by rank within their suit (where A(Ace)< 2 < 3 < … < 10 < J(Jack) < Q(Oueen) < K(King)). For example, the array ["8H","10H","QD","JD","4S"] (i.e., 8 of Hearts, 10 of Hearts, Queen of Diamonds, Jack of Diamonds, 4 of Spades) is sorted into the sorted array: ["JD","QD","8H","10H","4S"].

This is the code I've been given as an answer but I do not understand what the second for-loop in the sortCards method is doing. If you're already going through the array in the first for-loop then what is the second doing?

```
public class Cards {
 public static String[] sortCards(String[] s){ // SELECT SORT
 for (int i = s.length - 1; i >= 1; i--){
     // Find the maximum in the list[0..i]
     String currentMax = s[0];
     int currentMaxIndex = 0;
     for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
         if (cardLessThan(currentMax,s[j])){
             currentMax = s[j];
             currentMaxIndex = j;
         }
     }
     // Swap list[i] with s[currentMaxIndex] if necessary;
     if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
         s[currentMaxIndex] = s[i];
         s[i] = currentMax;
     }
 }  
 return s;
}
static boolean cardLessThan(String s1, String s2){
   char s1s = s1.charAt(s1.length()-1); //suites
   char s2s = s2.charAt(s2.length()-1);
   if(s1s < s2s)
       return true;
   else if(s1s > s2s)
       return false;
   // Same suite cards - order determined by card number
 String n1 = s1.substring(0,s1.length()-1);
 String n2 = s2.substring(0,s2.length()-1);
 if(n1.equals("A") && !n2.equals("A")) return true;
 if(n1.equals("2") && !n2.equals("A") && !n2.equals("2")) return true;
 …
 return false;
 }`
```

Comment: It's a Selection Sort.  Look at the [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort); the pseudocode there also has two loops.

Comment: @khelwood: already fixed.

Comment: Please work on articulating what you're doing without dumping your homework reqs. That preamble says nothing about your problem, and is most likely irrelevant to it.

Comment: `// Find the maximum in the list[0..i]` tells you exactly what the inner for loop is doing; finding the maximum value in the unsorted portion of the array.

Comment: well, @CheifTwoPencils that preamble literally says the question for the problem and whatI I don't understand about the code, and therefore has everything to do with it. Next time please don't respond if you don't have a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is similar to a BubbleSort algorithm, the inner loop is to find the value if any that needs to be swapped to the current slot of the array

here is an example using a number array

say you have 10 numbers in an array

1 2 5 7 8 3 4 6 9 0

you want to sort them from highest to lowest

after one iteration of the code you provided if it was set for integers would look like this

9 2 5 7 8 3 4 6 1 0

it found the 9 and swapped the 1 with it so the 9 is now at the top of the list
and it will do this for the entire array until the array looks like this

9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Comment: Very true that is why I said similar in that it finds the highest value and swaps but does not continually swap through the iteration.  Although my example of what it does with the array/list is accurate.

Comment: It could be me but it doesn't "look" like that's what you're saying. See the very slow but correct animation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#mediaviewer/File:Bubble-sort-example-300px.gif).

Answer (score 0):

In a sort code when you need to replace a card at a position x you need to do a swap.

Here, first loop is doing loop for all your card and for each card the second loop try to see if the next one is greater then current, if yes swap is done
If no nothing happen.

Its pretty simple no?:)

You need to see algorithm about sort to understand clearly this.

Good luck;)